# Loading an external template in GAE application?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-templates

Is there a way to load a template from a source which is not hosted on the application itself?  For example, in order to load a template on the application itself (hosted by the appengine app):

```
html = template.render("admin/my_template.html", params)
```

I would like to do something like:

```
html = template.render("http://www.otherhost.com/external_template.html", params)
```

Is there a mechanism to allow such a behavior?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example of why you might want to do this? Are you sure the external file is actually a Django template, and not simply a static HTML page?

Comment: If the file is part of the application, every time i want to change it I need to re-deploy the whole app. If the template is external on the other hand I can edit it independently.

Comment: Well, loading it from an external site doesn't seem like a good way to solve that problem - think of the added latency, for example. Maybe you could consider loading it from the datastore, or Cloud Storage?

Comment: I'm using those templates mainly to send emails - so latency is not an issue here. Keeping it in a datastore will require an implementation of an editor for the HTML in the database etc. But if there's no simple solution for loading files from else, I'll probably have to go for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ofcourse you can load templates from other apps. To load templates you have to fetch the templates.

But using an editor is also not very difficult. I use codemirror to edit a HTML textarea.
See this list of demos : http://codemirror.net/demo/

Editing a Jinja txt mail template example:[image]

Answer (score 0):

Templates are just strings. If you can get the text, you can parse it as a template.

In this case you would need to make a request for the file using `urllib`, get the response, and then use `template.Template(content)` to convert it to a template object.

However, I must say I still think keeping it in the datastore is a better bet. I'm not sure why you would need an editor for that - why not just cut and paste the content into a field in the GAE admin console, or using the remote API to set it?